# unexpected charcters appears after writing it into a text file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

when i try to get the text from a document, if it is followed by some special characters such as TM or C (for copyright) and so on, after writing it into a text file it will makes some unexpected added to it. as an example, we can consider the following:

if we have `Apache™ Hadoop™!` and then if we try to write in into a text using `FileOutputStream` then result would be like `Apacheâ Hadoopâ` which the `â` is nonsense for me and generally i want a way to detect such characters in the text and just skipping them for writing them, is there solution to this?

Comment: What character encoding are you using to write the file?

Comment: @GregKopff i dont know, maybe default cause i just simply make a **FileOutputStream** and then using the write() method to write into a text file

Comment: Define "such characters". Do you want to skip everything except ASCII characters? Including those that may be part of people's names? It#s generally a very bad idea to deliberately lose data.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt yea i just want the ASCII codes, for my work its ok if its a part of people's name, cause before this phase those special would be deleted , so can you propose any solution for detecting and skipping these non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the printable ASCII range, then iterate over your string character by character building a new string.  Include the character only if it's within the range `0x20` to `0x7E`.

```
final StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : string.toCharArray())
{
  if (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7E)
  {
    buff.append(c);
  }
}

final FileWriter w = new FileWriter(...);
w.write(buff.toString());
w.close();
```

If you want to keep carriage returns and newlines, you also need to consider `0x0A` and `0x0D`.

Answer (score 0):

I mis-read the question originally and didn't notice you wanted to skip them.  I'll leave this here for now and will delete it if someone posts something better.

---

To deal with the characters properly, you can explicit setg the charset to ISO-8859-1.  To do this, you'll need to use something like an `OutputStreamWriter`.

```
final OutputStreamWriter writer;

writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),
                                Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
writer.write(string);
writer.close();
```

This won't skip them, but should encode them properly.

Comment: will it ignore the TM when i try to write them?  mean i wish there is a way to ignore such characters then for example **Apache™** will be regarded as **Apache** before writing happens

Comment: You can try UTF-8 encoding - but also be aware that what ever program you're opening the text file with also needs to be aware of character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is characters coding problem. Before you write the string into file, you need to coding the String characters.
you can use like follow:

```
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(   
                        new File("D://helloWorld.txt")), "UTF8");
    String tm ="Apache™ Hadoop™";
    out.write(tm);
    out.close();
```

Comment: your answer is right, but if you can give me a way to write it as 
**Apache Hadoop** then i would be grateful

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your mean.

Comment: He wants to skip characters that aren't in the ASCII charset.

Comment: @user1064929 you could't need to skip the special characters, by using the UTF8 encode,the result would not be like Apacheâ Hadoopâ . If you skip it , maybe the result is not what you really want.